# SSRS limitation : Not able to show RTF data in SSRS Report

Tags: c#, .net, reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-2012

I am trying to find a way to display data in SSRS Report which is coming from database and its stores in the form of .rft code in the database. I know Crystal Report can read rtf code
and we can set Text Interpretation to none/Html/RTF. But in SSRS we can only set Markup Type as None-Pain Text Only/ HTML - Interpret HTML tags as styles. There is no option for RTF on any SSRS version

Also I need to know can we display .rtf file in SSRS Report like image files (JPEG).

Comment: Did you try with `PlaceHolder`? I think this [MSDN post](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645967.aspx) will be helpful for you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35280740/ssrs-report-builder-not-showing-rich-text-from-db-properly-still-showing-tags

Comment: using PlaceHolder we can only set HTML- Interpret HTML tags as styles

Comment: But you can show your .rtf file as an image right.

Comment: How I can show .rtf file as an image in SSRS...we can load only jpg, gif, png or bmp files